# Error Code: 1318. Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE 2.procedurainot111; expected 3, got 1

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedurainot111` (out kol_sotr INT, out sumpokaz INT, IN number_otd int) 
BEGIN 
SELECT COUNT(номер_отдела), sum(показатели) INTO kol_sotr, sumpokaz
FROM сотрудники WHERE номер_отдела=number_otd;
END //
DELIMITER ;
call procedurainot111('1')
```

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough? Any answer will simply repeat the message, you need 3 arguments but gave only 1. Perhaps some hints : you need variables to store the `out` ones

Comment: mysql needs to know where to put the out values see manual for an example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Can you show an example of what to write after "call peocedurainot111(............."?

Comment: You have examples in the documentation provided just above. happy reading and coding :)